# Boost Python sizeof class

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I have a simple class in C++:

```
class Foo {
    char arr[5];
};
static_assert(sizeof(Foo) == 5);
```

I expose this class using Boost Python:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
    boost::python::class_<Foo>("Foo");
}
```

Now I want to get the size of the C++ class, from Python.  I tried these:

```
example.Foo().__instance_size__
example.Foo().__sizeof__()
```

But they give `24` and `48` which are obviously not what I'm after.

Is there any better way than to implement and bind a method explicitly?